# How to configure webpack 4 to prevent chunks from list of entry points appearing in any other bundle?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I am working on a large project and trying to land webpack 3 -> 4 update. This app has somewhere around 1,000 entry points, and about 10 of those are considered "global" or "core" and guaranteed to be on every page. These core bundles contain a mix of vendor and non-vendor code. I need to configure webpack to build all of these assets so that any chunks appearing in any of these bundles will not appear in any other bundle regardless of the size of the chunk, without creating new assets that need to be added to the page.

With webpack 3, we have been using CommonsChunkPlugin to accomplish this. Here's a simple example:

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'a-global-bundle',
  minChunks: Infinity,
}),
```

Now with webpack 4 and the removal of CommonsChunkPlugin, it isn't clear to me how to accomplish this sort of optimization.

I'd like to be able to give webpack a list of entry points and any chunks that appear in any of those will not appear in any other bundle, but I'm not sure how to do this. I've read through [some forthcoming documentation on `splitChunks`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org/pull/1863/files) but I haven't been able to piece together a solution.

I've set up a small repo as a starting point to tinker with: https://github.com/lencioni/webpack-splitchunks-playground

One interesting direction I'm trying out is configuring `cacheGroups` with a group for each of these entry points and implementing the `test` option with a function that does this check. However, the documentation is pretty sparse on this, so I'm not really sure what the right way to write this test function would be or even if this will work at all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, so I think I have figured out how to do this. But first, here's what the build looks like with the default splitChunks configuration (note FOO.bundle.js is an async bundle created by a dynamic import):

```js
            Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
   core.bundle.js    605 KiB       0  [emitted]  [big]  core
  coreB.bundle.js    791 KiB       1  [emitted]  [big]  coreB
  coreC.bundle.js    791 KiB       2  [emitted]  [big]  coreC
      a.bundle.js    748 KiB       3  [emitted]  [big]  a
      b.bundle.js    792 KiB       4  [emitted]  [big]  b
      c.bundle.js    674 KiB       5  [emitted]  [big]  c
    FOO.bundle.js  709 bytes       6  [emitted]         FOO
runtime.bundle.js   7.49 KiB       7  [emitted]         runtime
```

If the goal is to make it so any modules appearing in core, coreB, and coreC won't appear in any other bundle, this can be done with the following configuration:

```js
function coreBundleCacheGroups(coreBundles) {
  const cacheGroups = {};
  const coreChunkNames = Object.keys(coreBundles);
  const coreChunkNamesSet = new Set(coreChunkNames);


  coreChunkNames.forEach((name) => {
    cacheGroups[name] = {
      name,
      chunks: 'all',
      minSize: 0,
      minChunks: 1,
      reuseExistingChunk: true,
      priority: 10000,
      enforce: true,
      test(module, chunks) {
        if (module.depth === 0) {
          return false;
        }

        // Find first core chunk name that matches
        const partOfGlobalChunks = chunks.filter(chunk => coreChunkNamesSet.has(chunk.name));

        if (!partOfGlobalChunks.length) {
          return false;
        }

        const partOfGlobalChunksSet = new Set(partOfGlobalChunks.map(chunk => chunk.name));
        const firstCoreChunkName = coreChunkNames.find(name => partOfGlobalChunksSet.has(name));
        return firstCoreChunkName === name;
      },
    };
  });

  return cacheGroups;
}

const coreBundles = {
  core: './src/bundles/core.js',
  coreB: './src/bundles/core-b.js',
  coreC: './src/bundles/core-c.js',
};

module.exports = {
  mode: 'none',

  entry: {
    ...coreBundles,
    a: './src/bundles/a.js',
    b: './src/bundles/b.js',
    c: './src/bundles/c.js',
  },

  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },

  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: 'single',

    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        ...coreBundleCacheGroups(coreBundles),
      },
    },
  },
};
```

which produces the following output:

```js
            Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
   core.bundle.js    605 KiB       0  [emitted]  [big]  core
  coreB.bundle.js    188 KiB       1  [emitted]         coreB
  coreC.bundle.js    1.5 KiB       2  [emitted]         coreC
      a.bundle.js   76.4 KiB       3  [emitted]         a
      b.bundle.js   2.28 KiB       4  [emitted]         b
      c.bundle.js   1.91 KiB       5  [emitted]         c
    FOO.bundle.js  622 bytes       6  [emitted]         FOO
runtime.bundle.js   7.49 KiB       7  [emitted]         runtime
```

Answer (score 3):

Your current config (using Webpack 3) uses `CommonsChunkPlugin` for an [Explicit vendor chunk](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/#explicit-vendor-chunk):

> Split your code into vendor and application.

Checking the Webpack output for your [repo](https://github.com/lencioni/webpack-splitchunks-playground) I found that `a.bundle.js` contains the following code:

```
// `react`, `react-dom` plus
console.log('core module');     // from core-module.js
console.log('core module b');   // from core-module-b.js
console.log('non-core module'); // from non-core-module.js
```

Similar code is inside `b.bundle.js` (the difference in this script is the last `console.log` which is referenced from `non-core-module-b.js`: `console.log('non-core module b');`).

Updating the `webpack.config.js` optimization option to:

```
optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: 'single',

    splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',

        cacheGroups: {
            default: {
                enforce: true,
                priority: 1
            },
            vendors: {
                test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                priority: 2,
                name: 'vendors',
                enforce: true,
                chunks: 'all'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Produce a non duplication code between the bundles.

---

You can check the working code [here](https://github.com/carloluis/webpack-splitchunks-playground).
I also created a [pull request](https://github.com/lencioni/webpack-splitchunks-playground/pull/1) to your sample project.

More info about [code splitting and the splitChunks optimization](https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-4-code-splitting-chunk-graph-and-the-splitchunks-optimization-be739a861366)

Comment: Thanks for digging in and putting together a PR! Unfortunately, this isn't quite what I need. I need a solution that keeps the chunks in these core bundles without creating new assets. I'll try to clarify my question some more.

Comment: I think this might be what I need. I need to do more testing, but it seems to be pretty close. https://github.com/lencioni/webpack-splitchunks-playground/pull/3

Comment: Ok. I just checked! So, I missed the initial intention.. You don't want to create any other bundle beyond your entrypoints, not even for the vendors and instead those third party dependencies should be keep in one or several of the core bundles. 
I would probably follow the same path creating an entry on `cacheGroup` per each `core*` on the entrypoints. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

> Our goal is to configure webpack to build our assets so that any
>   chunks that appear in any of these bundles will not appear in any
>   other bundle.

What I had before:

```
            new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
                name: 'vendor',
                minChunks: function (module, count) {
                    // this assumes your vendor imports exist in the node_modules directory and module should be required
                    // in at least 3 entries before it moved to common chunk
                    return (module.context && module.context.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1) && count > 2;
                }
            }),
```

How it works now:

```
        optimization: {
            splitChunks: {
                cacheGroups: {
                    vendor: {
                        test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                        chunks: 'all',
                        name: 'vendor',
                        enforce: true,
                        minChunks: 3
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```